# Where Are WordPress nonces Stored?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to figure out where does WordPress store all the nonces. But wasn't able to find a clue.
I first checked the database but wasn't able to find any table named something like wp_nonces.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with nonces: [«A nonce is a **number used once** to help protect URLs and forms from certain types of misuse, malicious or otherwise. WordPress **nonces aren't numbers, but are a hash** made up of numbers and letters»](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I posted this question 11 months ago.

All the answers that I received were great and helped me a lot.

But none of them addressed the storage location of WordPress nonces. That's what my real question was.

So, I dug up WordPress source code and was able to find the correct storage location of WordPress nonces.

They are stored in user sessions.

They are unique tokens stored in user's session. Nonces have a defined life span.

If the user logs out of WordPress, the nonces will no longer be valid.

**PS:** I asked this question and now I am posting this answer to help others :)

Comment: One important thing. While it is true that the nonce gets devaluated when logging out, nonces are not related to the authentication itself. Those are different processes. By default the authentication is done by cookies in WordPress. If for example you try to access protected posts via WP REST API and provide just the nonce your request will be rejected even you are logged in. You have to use JWT to authenticate your API requests. The nonces themselves do not provide any user authentication.

Comment: Nonces are not stored anywhere, they are computed and verified on the fly based on some input data.

Comment: Do you mean sessions that are stored in the `wp_usermeta` table with `session_tokens` meta key?

Answer (score 4):

Nonces are not stored directly anywhere, they are created using the function [`wp_create_nonce`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1794) and validated using the [`wp_verify_nonce`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1745).

Those functions in turn use `wp_hash` to hash together a lifespan, a custom string, the user_id and the session token stored in wp_usermeta with the key `session_tokens`.

Answer (score -1):

Nonces are one-time tokens generated by WordPress to validate various requests, such as adding a comment, deleting a post, removing a user, etc.

They're not stored anywhere, nor do they need to be.

Take the following example; when managing content in WordPress, the **Bin** link may look something like this:

`http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1337&action=trash&_wpnonce=369f188682`

However, if you were to try and change the ID of the page/post in the URL to something else (*see below*), the nonce would no longer be valid, return a 403 error, and display: "Are you sure you want to do this?"

`http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=9100&action=trash&_wpnonce=369f188682`

Adding a hidden `_nonce` field (take [Contact Form 7](http://www.contactform7.com) as a prime example) is generally good practice when implementing forms into WordPress, as it prevents Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF), etc.

**Resources:**

- [WordPress Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)
- [Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Nonce)
- [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: This still doesn't answer my query. If WordPress doesn't store the nonces anywhere then how does it validate/verify them? :)

Comment: From [WordPress Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces): "Nonces are unique to the current user's session, so if a user logs in or out asynchronously any nonces on the page will no longer be valid."

Comment: @bluemwhitew at this point my question is: what's the meaning of user's session? Is it the session generated through php `session_start()` or what else. As far as I know wordpress doesn't use php sessions.