# Wordpress login URL with prefilled login details

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's say the login URL for my WordPress site is http://www.mycoolwoordpresssite.com/login, and this is what a client sees when he follows the link:
[image]
But in order to make it easy for my clients I want the User-Name and Password fields will already be filled with the credentials.
for example, if I'll provide a link that goes something like this:
http://www.mycoolwoordpresssite.com/login?user=simon?passwd=12345, The fields in the login page will already be filled up with: 
**User-Name:** simon 
**Password:** ***** // (12345)
And the only thing left for the client is to hit the "Log In" Button and tell his browser to save the password. It should look like:
[image]
I know it is not the safest thing to do in terms of website security, but it will be used just for subscriber accounts without any privileges.

Comment: Use query strings and global variable ($_GET) and set default values for the Input fields.

Comment: `I know it is not the safest thing to do in terms of website security,` . **Understatement**. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is not the safest thing to do in terms of website security

**Understatement.**

Don't do it.

If you want people to be able to already log in you should use a form of `cookie`. Wordpress has this already with the `"Remember me"` tick box. Your clients type their details in once, and bang, they're remembered.

If you persistantly feel that clients can not or should not know or use their access details, you can send your clients a unique hash (via email) they can click on to a custom page of yours (on the same site) to simply generate the cookie which they can then use to log in.

This unique hash would need to either be stored with their row in the database *or* would be mathematically decrypted somehow to reveal their row ( **not recommended** ). Once the hash is used you should delete it or disable it.

Example:

> ```
>  https://www.mycoolwoordpresssite.com/access.php?h=rger24FE32GSdsgd12d46sgso90FDGSFF
> ```

## Some related questions and answers that may help you:

- [Where Are WordPress nonces Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744442/where-are-wordpress-nonces-stored)
- [how to auto login a user](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-auto-login-a-user/) (*WP forum*)
- [auto login new user after registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-login-new-user-after-registration/) (*WP addon*)
- [WordPress Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) (*documentation*)
- [allow wordpress automatic login via a given url](https://klaeser.me/2014/11/allow-wordpress-automatic-login-via-a-given-url/) (*code; may be out of date*)
- [Some relevant code](https://gist.github.com/cliffordp/e8d1d9f732328ba360ad) (*github*)
- [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe it's a bad idea to auto-populate the password, but the username is a different story. When curating a user's first impression with a website, imagine a welcome email that has a jovial button for them to log in for the first time. The automagic of the link adding the username for the user is sure to impress and jeopardizes no security measures.

Comment: @1934286 your view is very ...er, blinkered. What if the username is an email address, as is already common? Therefore if that username is available to a 3rd party listener they can then create fake emails from the [real] website and encourage spoofing email attacks. "click here to confirm you visited <this website>!" etc.

Comment: @1934286 This is why it is best practise for failure to login NOT to disclose if it was the email address / username or the password that failed, to stop people fishing if xxx@yyy email is associated with zzz.com website.